# PhpStorm LESS > CSS File watcher, auto upload?

Tags: upload, phpstorm, file-watcher

I'm using PhpStorm 9 and in all my projects I use LESS and let PhpStorm transpile it to CSS.

The thing is that if I have my deployment option "Upload changed files automatically to the default server" set to "upload on explicit save", it will upload the LESS file after I edited it, but it won't upload the child CSS automatically. If I save the LESS file a second time, triggering another upload, the css file does upload. Basically this results in me having to double-save all the time in order to get my style change visible. Is there any way I can make this happen without having to change this deployment setting to "always"?

I have "Upload external changes" checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has resolved itself since the 10.0 release of PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that `Output paths to refresh` field of File Watcher settings points to the actual file that is generated by this File Watcher -- that's how IDE watches for changes (knows what file was generated; e.g. it uses this info to nest generated files under source one in Project View).
2. If it still does not work (everything is set up correctly) .. then wait for next version (whatever it will be 9.0.3 or 9.5) -- this [WI-16410](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410) ticket should resolve it (already fixed).

**P.S.**
There is no real need to run File Watcher twice/modify and save LESS file for second time -- try `File | Synchronize` instead -- it will check project files looking for changes and should upload generated file if `Upload external changes` option is enabled (File Watcher is considered an external tool).